# Android - как сделать EditText неактивным, в то же самое время сохраняя курсор?

Tags: java, android, xml

Я разрабатываю клавиатуру используя EditText и Button-ы. При нажатии на кнопку, текстовое поле заполняется соответствующей буквой. Сделал поле неактивным, чтобы нельзя было вводить посторонние буквы, но в то же время текст можно выделить и копировать.

```
android:enabled="false"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Однако при таком коде курсор исчезает. А мне нужно, чтобы он оставался видимым, чтобы знать, с какого места можно стереть или добавить текст. Как могу сделать курсор видимым?

Comment: Обычно используют listener'ы для реакции на события, и при необходимости отменяют их. Я немного поискал по вашей проблеме, посмотрите этот вопрос по ссылке, может быть будет полезно (автор искал способ отследить нажатие backspace, но оказалось, что listener вызывается только с hardware-клавиатурой, в ответах есть варианты обхода и этой проблемы): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event

Comment: посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174606/disable-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-but-still-allow-copy-paste/20173020#20173020

Comment: Мне нужно, что мигающий курсор никогда не исчез, а при данных решениях он всеравно изчезает и никогда не появляется.